# Dockerized apache gives forbidden on folder starting with dot, even after several attempts

Tags: apache-2.4, docker

thanks for looking at my question. I am trying to run a BOLT cms in a docker container with apache. I want to be able to view a folder located on the webserver at:
http:///async/browse/cache/.version/
and in the filesystem it is at.
/var/www/html/app/cache/.version/
but no matter what I do I get forbidden.

I have tried:

Adding a new .htaccess file in the folder with:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

I have also tried editing the autoindex.conf file so that I should be able to view all files and folders starting with a dot.

From setting the logs to debug I see the following, but from my understanding I should be able to view the folder?
[Screenshot of the debug output, saying granted, but the browser says forbidden][1]

I am not sure if this adds enough information, I would be eternally grateful for help.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn3h7.png

Comment: I am very aware of the security problems with this, it is intentionally vulnerable since it is part of a pentesting training.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output. Paste the text into your message instead, so it's readable by screen readers and search engines.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. You have a deny rule somewhere else in your configuration for files named `.*`. This is common. But it doesn't seem to be the case here since your debug output shows that Apache granted the request.
2. The file system permissions on that directory don't give Apache permission to read it. Check that it has at least `rx` permissions for Apache or all users.

Also, note that the `Order` and `Allow` directives are deprecated in Apache 2.4. You should use `Require all granted` instead. See [Require](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).